# Update Azure SDK without "helpful" page launch?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

So, I've just updated the Azure SDK for the (who knows how many versions?) time and on my second machine.

I really don't need to see guidance on what's new or "getting started".

So does anyone know how to say "stop, I don't need you to do that" on or before I hit this screen:

[image: Azure SDK and Tools Configure Page]

Comment: Is installing the SDK using MSI based installer an option for you?

Comment: @GauravMantri - the options seem to be "use Web PI" or "here are a thousand different MSIs for you to separately download and install". I was kind of hoping for some kind of middle ground.

Comment: Aah...I see. As of now I don't think there's a middle ground. Though I have not tried it, could using WebpiCmdline (http://blogs.iis.net/satishl/webpi-command-line) be of some help to you?